# Why doe the hook fire itself in an infinite loop when I am passing the update props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have created a custom hook that makes an HTTP request. But the problem is that it makes requests in an infinite loop. I cannot understand the reason for this. I want the request to fire, if there is either a change in `fetchConfig` or `action`

```
 export default function useBrokerFetch<T>(fetchConfig: { [key: string]: any }, action: BrokerActions): [T, boolean] {

    const [data, setData] = useState(null as T);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const brokerEndPoint = process.env.REACT_APP_APIBROKER_ENDPOINT;

    async function fetchUrl() {
        try {

            const {data} = await BrokerHttpRequest(new Request(brokerEndPoint, {
                headers: {
                    "Accept": "application/json",
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                },
                method: "POST",
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    "data": fetchConfig,
                    "signature": BrokerServiceProviders.WMS,
                    "action": action
                })
            }));
            if (data) {
                setData(data);
                setLoading(false);
            } else {
                /**
                 * The request with the broker failed or the broker
                 * did not return any data. In either case, set the
                 * broker data to undefined and update the loading
                 * state to "not-loading"
                 */
                setData(undefined as T);
                setLoading(false);
            }
        } catch (err) {
            setData(undefined as T);
            setLoading(false);
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchUrl();
    }, [fetchConfig, action]);


    return [data, loading];
}
```

What is it that I am doing wrong?

Comment: how is called your custom hook `useBrokerFetch` ? If you pass a new object in one of the arguments `fetchConfig` or `action`, then the function `fetchUrl` will be called infinitely

Comment: @OlivierBoissé I pass a new object when I call the function. Is there a way to fire the hook every time I call it? Since it is an HTTP hook making an HTTP call, I want it to fire every time I call.

Comment: If you fire a http request every time you call the hook you will get an infinite loop. The HTTP call updates a state variable (`data` and `loading`) so the component will be re-rendered, when the component re-render, it will call the hook which will fire an http call which will updates the state variables which will trigger a re-render... Do you see the infinite loop ? I think you should pass a new object each time you call the hook otherwise you will get an infinite loop

Comment: @OlivierBoissé I do get an infinite loop. Could you show how can I do this with a small example?

Comment: you just need to not pass a new object for the `fetchConfig` when you call your custom hook, maybe useMemo would help you https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo

Comment: @Amanda are you sure that BrokerHttpRequest returns a Promise?

Answer (score 0):

So I am not an expert on react but here are my 2 cents. I think every time you update "data" in your http-request your parent component depends on it an re-renders. When the parent re-renders their objects/child components are initialized again and useBrokerFetch is called again.
In this case "data" or "actions" might still be of the same value but for useEffect it matters if the "are equal" to the props provided. Since the parent re-rendered they are not the same. Please keep in mind, that also functions are up to change in JS.
I recommend the useCallback-Hook to you. With useCallback() you can basically cache a value you then provide as props to useBrokerFetch(). When your parent re-renders the props action and data stay equal and useEffect should not be called again. You use useCallback similar to useEffect, check out the docs.